# Why C11 standard doesn't drop unsafe strcat(),strcpy() functions?

Tags: c, strcpy, c11, strcat

`C11` & `C++14` standards have dropped `gets()` function that is inherently insecure & leads to security problems because it doesn't performs bounds checking results in buffer overflow. Then why `C11` standard doesn't drop `strcat()` & `strcpy()` functions? `strcat()` function doesn't check to see whether second string will fit in the 1st array. `strcpy()` function also contains no provision for checking boundary of target array. What if the source array has more characters than destination array can hold? Most probably program will crash at runtime.

So, wouldn't it be nice if these two unsafe functions completely removed from the language? Why they are still exist? What is the reason? Wouldn't it is fine to have only functions like `strncat(),strncpy()`? If I am not wrong Microsoft C & C++ compiler provides safe versions of these functions `strcpy_s(),strcat_s()`. Then why they aren't officially implemented by other C compilers to provide safety?

Comment: I believe xkcd covered this with [Standards](https://xkcd.com/927/), see also `strncpy` and `strncat`.

Comment: I guess because `gets` is never within the programmer's control, while `strcpy` and `strcat` can be used in places where the programmer is in control of the length and knows what they are doing.

Comment: If the standard was to drop all functions that can be used wrong there would very few functions left.

Comment: In this regard, array has no bound checking in `C` making it kind of _unsafe_, so can it be dropped from `C`? :-)

Comment: When I type "man gets" I see label "(depricated)". When I type "man strcpy" I don't see such label. May be they just removed deprecated functions from standart library, as they are declared depricated.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, it can't be dropped from C. As a programmer, it is your responsibility to ensure that every access to array elements doesn't exceed to boundary of array. It is the price paid for performance. Performing runtime checks can dramatically affect the performance of program. So, this is something that we as a programmer need to live with.

Comment: @meet My question was rhetorical, anyway. Did you realize you yourself answered this question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Oh, yes !!!

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious: `gets()` was deprecated by the 1999 ISO C standard, and removed altogether by the 2011 standard. I don't believe that any other function in the C standard library has ever been deprecated or removed.

Comment: [This answers the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23490019/584518).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`gets()` is inherently unsafe, because in general it can overflow the target if too much data is received on `stdin`.  This:

```
char s[MANY];
gets(s);
```

will cause undefined behavior if more than `MANY` characters are entered, and there is typically nothing the program can do to prevent it.

`strcpy()` and `strcat()` can be used *completely safely*, since they can overflow the target only if the source string is too long to be contained in the target array. The source string is contained in an array object that is under the control of the program itself, not of any external input. For example, this:

```
char s[100];
strcpy(s, "hello");
strcat(s, ", ");
strcat(s, "world");
```

cannot possibly overflow unless the program itself is modified.

`strncat()` can be used as a safer version of `strcat()` -- as long as you specify the third argument correctly. One problem with `strncat()` is that it only gives you one way of handling the case where there's not enough room in the target array: it silently truncates the string. Sometimes that might be what you want, but sometimes you might want to detect the overflow and do something about it.

As for `strncpy()`, it is *not* simply a safer version of `strcpy()`. It's not inherently dangerous, but if you're not very careful you can easily leave the target array without a terminating `'\0'` null character, leading to undefined behavior next time you pass it to a function expecting a pointer to a string. As it happens, [I've written about this](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: Incidentally; I've reason to believe the original gets() stopped at 1024 characters but it wasn't written into the standard so later gets() didn't stop. I've ran into gets() that stopped from time to time.

Comment: The earlier `gets()` implementation I could find was from V6 UNIX, 1975. It has no such limitation. There might have been a limitation imposed by the tty driver, but that wouldn't affect programs whose stdin is redirected from a file. http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/iolib/gets.c

Answer (score 5):

`strcpy` and `strcat` aren't similar to `gets`. The problem of `gets` is, it's used to read from input, so it's out of the programmer's control whether there will be buffer overflow.

---

C99 Rational explains `strncpy` as:

> #### [Rationale for International Standard — Programming Languages — C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) §7.21.2.4 The `strncpy` function
>
> `strncpy` was initially introduced into the C library to deal with fixed-length name fields in structures such as directory entries. Such fields are not used in the same way as strings: the trailing null is unnecessary for a maximum-length field, and setting trailing bytes for shorter 5 names to null assures efficient field-wise comparisons. **`strncpy` is not by origin a “bounded `strcpy`,”** and the Committee preferred to recognize existing practice rather than alter the function to better suit it to such use.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the reason why they kept strncpy was documented in the rationale.

Answer (score 3):

- Myth 1: strcpy() is unsafe and how it works comes as a great surprise to a veteran C programmer.
- Myth 2: strncpy() is safe.
- Myth 3: strncpy() is a safer version of strcpy().
- Myth 4: Microsoft is some kind of authority of the use of the C language and know what they are talking about.

`strcat()` and `strcpy()` are [perfectly safe functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486938/c4996-function-unsafe-warning-for-strcpy-but-not-for-memcpy/23490019#23490019).

Also note that `strncpy` [was never intended to be a safe version of strcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure). It is used for an obscure, obsolete string format used in an ancient version of Unix. `strncpy` is actually [very unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure) ([one of many blog post about it here](http://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/)), unlike `strcpy`, since very few programmers seem to be able to use the former without producing fatal bugs (no null termination).

A better question is why the inherently unsafe `strncpy()` wasn't removed from the language. Is anyone working with obscure Unix strings from the 1970s much?

Comment: strncpy's format is *not* obsolete. It's obscure to you but it's not obscure to me. You depend on its behavior when working with certain kinds of filesystems including ext2. (I don't think the Linux kernel uses strncpy in ext2 but it could have as the filesystem on disk uses the format.)

Comment: @Joshua Of course it is obsolete, as far as standard C goes. The function should never have been included in the language to begin with, but should have remained as part of the OS-specific API. "It is used in *nix" is a very poor rationale for letting a non-generic, obscure function be part of the standard library.

Comment: By the time C was being bootstrapped out of Unix it was too late. They should have standardized strlcpy and strlcat instead but they hadn't appeared yet.

Answer (score 2):

When removing a function *completely*, one of the major things the standards have to mainly consider is how much of code it could break and how many people (programmers, library writers, compiler vendors, etc) would be annoyed (or would oppose) with the change.

`gets()` was deprecated from LSB (Linux Standard Base). POSIX-2008 made it obsolete and `gets()` has been historically known to be a *seriously* bad function and has always been strongly discouraged to use in any code. Pretty much every C programmer knew it's seriously dangerous to use `gets()`. So the chances of its removal breaking any production code is very very little, it not, non-existing. So it was easy to remove `gets()` from C11 for the committee.

But it's not the case with `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc. They can be used safely and it's still being used by many programmers in new code. While they can be subject to be buffer overflow, it's mostly programmer's control while `gets()` isn't.

There can be argument made to use `snprintf` in place of `strcpy` and `strcat`. But it would seem pointless in simple cases like:

```
char buf[256];
strcpy(buf, "hello");
```

(if `buf` was a pointer, then the allocate size need to tracked for use in `snprintf`)

because as a programmer, *I know*, the above is perfectly safe. More importantly a *lot* of legacy code would break. Basically, there's no such strong arguments can be made to remove `strcpy`, etc functions as they can be used safely.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is scenarios which will lead to undefined behavior.

Let's say

```
char a[3] = "string";
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
printf("%c\n",a[i]);
```

You have array out of bound access and the standard hasn't removed this because it is you who is assigning the value and it is under your control.

Same with `strcpy()` and `strcat()` .

So standard can't remove all scenarios leading to UB.

Whereas `gets()` we know is not under the programmers control and it is taking data from some stream and you never know what the input might be and there is a high probability you might end up with buffer overflow so it has been removed and a safer function `fgets()` has been added.

Comment: There's no out of bounds access or UB in your example.

Comment: @BlueMoon Wanted to show some array out of bound access and end up writing in-bound access code :)

Comment: `char a[3] = "string";` isn't a run-time buffer overflow, it's a *constraint violation* that will be detected at compile time. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9p2: "No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
being initialized."

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah I get it

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah I made my point clear by showing out of bound access which should be good

Comment: There's no out of bounds access if the code doesn't compile. (Some compilers, including gcc in its default mode, merely warn about the declaration, but compilers can and IMHO should treat it as a fatal error.)

Comment: I better example would have been `char a[3] = "str";`, which is actually let through by a loophole in the standard. However, I don't see what any of this has to do with the question.