# Why is the scanf_s function not taking input correctly?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar, c11, tr24731

When I input `a`, the output is `not a`. Condition is true so why is the output `not a`?. When I use `getchar` instead of `scanf_s`, it works fine. What's the issue?

```
char op;
scanf_s("%c", &op);
if ( op == 'a' )
    printf("the character is a");
else
    printf("not a");
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I don't know that. Just running it on Visual Studio 2013

Comment: try `scanf_s("%c", &op, 1);`

Comment: BLUEPIXY, can you please explain the 1 you added?

Comment: see [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try `scanf()` instead of `scanf_s()`.

Comment: VS will emit a warning (maybe an error) when using `scanf()`. This is annoying.

Comment: @Cool Guy http://stackoverflow.com/a/23487039/2410359 to quiet warning

Answer (score 2):

Specifier `%c` (two more such exceptions `%s`, `%[`) requires 3rd argument size-

```
scanf_s("%c", &op, 1);   // 1 to read single character
```

Answer (score 0):

The third argument should be `sizeof` the type. `scanf_s` is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to the integer constant `1` before including `<stdio.h>`.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char op;
scanf_s("%c", &op, sizeof(op));
if ( op == 'a' )
    printf("the character is a");
else
    printf("not a");
    return 0;
}
```