# How to convert current strcpy to strcpy_s?

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I have large project having `strcpy` used everywhere. I am thinking to use `strcpy_s` instead of `strcpy`. I think almost 10,000 times I have used `strcpy`. It's so cumbersome to change every `strcpy`. Is there any efficient way for conversion?

Comment: You mean besides the obvious? (I.e. global s&r, then fix everything that is broken). Everyplace that breaks, by definition, needs inspection anyway, so branch your code and see how bad the malaise is.

Comment: `strcpy_s()` is pointless anyway.

Comment: Since the size of `dest` could be declared anywhere, it seems very hard to do anything in an automated way.

Comment: 10,000 times! And why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @EOF *strcpy_s() is pointless anyway.* [Vendor lock-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in).

Comment: @AndrewHenle `strcpy_s()` is nowadays part of the C standard, with the C11 bounds-checking interface.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks.  I missed that over the years.  So it's a sane implementation of `strncpy()` then?

Comment: @AndrewHenle No, it is a bounds-checking version of `strcpy()`. `strncpy()` was never intended to be used for that - it was in fact not originally intended to be used for null-terminated strings.

Comment: @Lundin *`strncpy()` was never intended to be used for that - it was in fact not originally intended to be used for null-terminated strings*  So you're saying it's the **naming** of `strncpy()` that's insane, given that all the other `str*()` functions are intended for nul-terminated strings? ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle When they decided what would go into the standard library, they were looking at which functions that already existed in UNIX. Lots of unmentionable substances were smoked and the result was a pretty random, completely inconsistent standard library, with lots of outright bad and broken things in it. As for the specific case of `strncpy`, here is the history: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-are-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-insecure

Comment: Consider [n1967](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm) which proposes "... that Annex K be either removed from the next revision of the C standard, or deprecated and then removed."  Sure you want to switch code to `strcpy_s()`?  Recommend reading the "Common Mistakes" section to see what you are getting into.

Answer (score 6):

You really shouldn't do this without inspecting since the point of tightening up buffer management is lost if it's not done intelligently.

Since the nature of the destination buffer (static or heap allocation, for instance) is very important when it comes to the proper arguments for `strcpy_s()`, and that information of course is not present in the existing `strcpy()` call, you *must* add it in any way. This requires a human.

Often a call like `strcpy(dest, src);` can be transformed into `strcpy_s(dest, sizeof dest, src);`, but if `dest` is heap-allocated this will just be the size of the pointer rather than the pointed-at buffer which of course is wrong.

Comment: You'd have to be sure `dest` was declared an array! Because if `dest` is pointer this is typically be a code breaking catastrophe.

Comment: To further add confusion, at least one C++ vendor (MS) provides a template wrapper for deducing the `size_t` argument when using a declared-fixed destination `char` array (i.e. `char dst[N];  strcpy_s(dst, src);`). Thusly, depending on the language and vendor, blanket replacement of `strcpy` with `strcpy_s` will compile correctly in such use cases, leaving the places where compilation breaks being the actual raw pointers for dest arguments. I never know whether to thank them or curse them for that.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have to provide an additional parameter that can't be deduced (`size_t destsz`) that is required to be accurate to benefit from the change you've got a real problem.

An application with 10,000 uses of `strcpy()` sounds insane but you are where you are.

**First**
If your time/resources are limited then all I can suggest is a bit of risk assessment.
Which calls are copying external data (from a file, the operating system, the user, a port or socket, etc.).
Focus on making sure those don't overwrite and you'll be reducing risk more effectively.

**Second**
If you've got any standard variable names and standard 'max sizes' you might be able to do a bit of global search and replace.

Say if you use `filename` a lot and filenames are up to 255 characters (plus NUL) on your platform you can replace `strcpy(filename,` with (say) `strcpy_s(filename,FILENAME_MAX_SZ`.

If the code is 'all over the place' you've got a lot of work cut out.

Replacing `strcpy(v,` with `strcpy_s(v,SIZE_MAX` (use regular expressions) is a superficial bodge that doesn't actually gain you anything except for potentially sneaking under your organisations code quality script. I did not tell you to do this! ;)

**Third**
If you want to take a stroll in the world of C11 `_Generic` you can try something like:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int strcpy_s(char *dest,size_t destsz,const char *src){
    if(strlen(src)>=destsz){
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(dest,src);
    return 0;
}

char *d_strcpy(char *dest,const char *src){
#ifndef NDEBUG
 fprintf(stdout,"unsafe copy of %s\n",src);
#endif
    return strcpy(dest,src);
}


#define strcpy(dest,src) _Generic (dest,\
    char[100] : strcpy_s(dest,sizeof dest,src),\
    char*: d_strcpy(dest,src)\
    )

int main(void) {
    char a[100]={'A','B','\0'};
    char *b=malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    strcpy(a,"XXX");
    strcpy(b,"XYX");

    printf("%s %s\n",a,b);

    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately you do need to specify the array size so need to be using probably a limited list of 'max sizes' and while this should work on Clang (untested) it fails on GCC because they don't agree how to resolve the controlling type! See [Document: N1930 (controlling expression of _Generic)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1930.htm)

Happy hunting.

Comment: The controlling type thingie has been agreed upon. GCC was right.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to replace the strcpy() function? [There is nothing wrong with strcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23490019/584518). Dogmatically changing it to `strcpy_s` won't fix anything. What you need to do is to consider each and every individual case:

- Is the size of the source buffer known and is its contents verified?
- Is the source buffer even of a dynamic nature? Can it vary in size or do you know the maximum size at compile time?
- Is the size of the target buffer large enough? Is it at all pointing at allocated memory?

This isn't something unique to `strcpy` or even strings, but something that must be considered for every *array* in your code.