# How can I free a char* within a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, free

```
 1| typedef struct container{
 2|     char* abc;
 3| }container;
 4|
 5|
 6| int main(void){
 7|
 8|     container* xyz = malloc(sizeof(container));
 9| 
10|     xyz->abc = malloc(10);
11|     xyz->abc = "abcdefghi\0";
12| 
13|     free(xyz->abc);
14|     free(xyz);
15| }
```

According to Valgrind there's a leak on line 10. which means free(xyz->abc) isn't working. How can I free this?

Comment: Please do not tag `C++` if you aren't explicitly writing C++ code, this code is purely C.

Comment: @CoryKramer: If it's being passed through a C++ compiler, it's C++. Only the OP can tell us which is right.

Comment: use `strcpy()`  .

Comment: If you wanted to copy that string literal to your newly allocated memory you can use [`strcpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm)

Comment: @CoryKramer: Ew! No! `strncpy`, please...

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Well I'd say forget both and use `std::string` assignment, but C.... :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition both works well if you know how to use it

Comment: @RomMer: Yes, if you never make any mistakes, `strcpy` is just fine. So, you should also never assign `0` to your freed pointers, and you should never comment your code.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition or just understand what you're doing when you're programming ?

Answer (score 7):

You allocated 10 bytes, and stored a pointer to those bytes (`xyz->abc`) then you immediately replaced that pointer with a pointer to a string literal (`"abcdefghi\0"`).

There are several problems with your program:

1. Ten leaked bytes
2. Excess `\0` in string literal — why?
3. `free`-ing something you didn't `malloc` (the replaced pointer)
4. Using `malloc`/`free` in the first place (assuming the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag isn't spurious)

In C, use [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) to emplace `abcdefghi` into your dynamically-allocated buffer.

In C++, forget this and switch to [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Don't use `strncpy`. From your linked man page: "Notes. Some programmers consider strncpy() to be inefficient and error prone."  [Why are strlcpy and strlcat considered insecure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-are-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-insecure).

Comment: @Lundin: What a load of nonsense.

Comment: Umm no. Among veteran C programmers, `strncpy` is widely known to be dangerous, for the reason that people always use it incorrectly and screw up null termination. It was never intended as a bounds-checking version of `strcpy`, we nowadays have `strcpy_s` for that purpose (introduced with C11). There's a lot of brainwashed dogma around blindly replacing `strcpy` with `strncpy`. What one should do instead is of course to check the bounds before using `strcpy`, or alternatively use `memcpy` or `strcpy_s`.

Comment: @Lundin: We will just have to agree to (very, very strongly) disagree. It would also be nice if you would present your arguments without doing so in the form of insinuating (a) I'm not a veteran, just because I disagree with you, or (b) I'm brainwashed, or (c) I follow "dogma". Thanks.

Comment: If you wanted a respectful comment, you should probably not reply with "What a load of nonsense" with no counter arguments. Here's some arguments www.google.com then type `strncpy is dangerous`. The 5-10 first hits all look quite relevant. As for brainwashing, Microsoft has done a lot of that with VS false positive warning for the use of `strcpy`.

Comment: [Why is strncpy insecure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure)

Comment: As for veteran C programmers, they have already gone through all of these phases: 1) lets use `strcpy` 2) lets not use `strcpy`, random Microsoft dummies say its dangerous! Use `strncpy`. 3) Hmm `strncpy` kind of sucks I think. It is really hard to get the null termination right. 4) `strncpy` definitely sucks, why is this? Oh wow it wasn't intended to be used in the way I've been using it for years. Turns out it's a 1970s remain from UNIX that got included in the standard C library mostly by accident. 5) lets use `strcpy`.

Comment: Personally, I advocate the use of `strdup`, which would s available on all the platforms which interest me and is easily implemented if necessary. `xyz->abc = strdup("abcdedghi");` would have avoided all problems.

Comment: @rici: Much better - I'm going to steal that for my answer; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `xyz->abc` *finally* does not hold a pointer returned by memory allocator function, it holds the pointer to the first element of the array containing the string literal `"abcdefghi\0"`. You don't need to `free()` it.

Rather, passing `xyz->abc` to `free()` in current scenario causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so the answer boils down to, you **must not** attempt to pass a pointer to `free()` which is not returned by earlier `malloc()` and family or `NULL`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3

> [....] Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: `s/don't need to/must not/`

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Added a bit of clarification. Hope that's better.

Answer (score 1):

Put `strcpy( xyz->abc, "abcdefghi" );` at line 11.

With `xyz->abc = "abcdefghi\0";` you redirect `xyz->abc` pointer to static string and lose the allocated memory address. Then `free` will work with wrong address and will not free the dynamically allocated block. `\0` is not necessary as mentioned above by @BoundaryImposition - every double quote enclosed string is null terminated and you add extra 0.

Comment: No, this will cause UB by modifying a string literal. Further modifications are necessary.

Comment: Furthermore, `strcpy` is **dangerous** and should be avoided at all times.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I agree, but `malloc(10)` (constant) is another wrong decision. With `strcpy` the exact example will work.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition What is UB? why `strcpy` is dangerous?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Unlike `strncpy`, [strcpy() is perfectly safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23490019/584518).

Comment: @RoiHatam It is not dangerous, that's a wide-spread, incorrect myth. `strncpy` is however intrinsically dangerous and should never be used for any purpose.

Comment: Since `container.abc` is never used (in given code snippet) as a null-terminated string, it's perfectly valid to use `strncpy`. But it's essential to remember that `strncpy` should *never* be used with null-terminated strings.

Comment: This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.

Comment: @TobySpeight The questioner can think what is the difference. Otherwise there is no good perspective to become programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The value passed to `free()` must be a value returned by something like `malloc()` or `realloc()`. Any other value passed to `free()` is invalid.

Your code allocates memory using `malloc()` and assigns the result to `xyz->abc`. But the next line then assigns the address of `"abcdefghi\0"` to `xyz->abc`.

So at this point, `xyz->abc` *no longer holds the value returned by `malloc()`.*

And when you pass this value to `free()`, that is not valid, and no memory is freed. That is your leak.