# converting strcpy_s to strcpy CPP

Tags: c++, c, strcpy

can someone please convert this line:

strcpy_s(this->name, SIZE_NAME, d.getName());

to a strcpy function instead of strcpy_s?

thank you

Comment: why not use `std::string`s and get rid of `strcpy_x` completely, when you are writing c++?

Comment: Read the function documentation, then drop the size... that's pretty much it.

Comment: Do you need to copy all of the functionality of `strcpy_s`?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Because maybe wild and uncontrolled heap allocations aren't feasible for their product?

Comment: @Lundin I think you are exaggerating a bit, but I do get your point ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Why I avoid the C++ tag... too many knee-jerk dogmas based on religious believes and too little disassembly.

Comment: Note: `strncpy` might also be available to you. Like `strcpy_s` it reduces the possibility for a buffer overflow, but does it through truncation rather than a configurable handler.

Comment: @user4581301 -- yes, `strncpy` won't, on its own, overflow the buffer. But subsequent uses of the target array may well run off the end, since `strncpy` just stops when it hits the limit; it does not nul-terminate the array.

Comment: @PeteBecker I deserve scorn for not expanding on exactly what truncation entailed in this case. A truly nasty surprise if you didn't read the documentation and expect to be safe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcpy(this->name, d.getName());
```

That was easy

Comment: This will overflow the buffer while the original code won't. So this does something different from the original code which I don't think is what the OP wanted -- but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What makes you think `d.getName()` contains strings with uncontrolled length? strcpy works just fine if the size of the data is known in advance.

Comment: @Lundin The fact that someone chose to write this code using `strcpy_s` makes me think that and that someone who doesn't know the difference between `strcpy_s` and `strcpy` is trying to change it to use `strcpy` is the clincher.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Or they could simply be using MSVC which gives very strange diagnostics. There need not be a rationale other than ""Microsoft told me to".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486938/c4996-function-unsafe-warning-for-strcpy-but-not-for-memcpy/23490019#23490019

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, unfortunately, given that `strcpy_s` is a quirky function too.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz And C11 `strcpy_s` in optional bounds-checking interface, which may or may not be compatible with MS libs, didn't exactly improve the situation. My take is that `_s` suffix means that the function is un`s`afe and non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
if (strlen(d.getName()) >= SIZE_NAME) {
    throw std::runtime_error("There was a bug. Contact your programmer and tell them to use std::string");
}
strcpy(this->name, d.getName());
```

Comment: "Contact your programmer and tell them to use std::string" error message is funny, assuming you talk to yourself. :)